# Is it possible to format an ordered list with hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: html, css

I don't want my `<ol>` items to be rendered as `1, 2, 3 ... 9, 10`, I want them to be numbered like this `0x01, 0x02 ... 0x09, 0x0a`.  Is this possible somehow?

Comment: manually via `content:` yes, not automatically though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a little bit of JavaScript.  Here's a snippet that uses the help of jQuery.

```
$('li').each(function(index){
   $(this).text('0x' + (index + 1).toString(16) + ' ' + $(this).text());
});
```

Here's a sample of it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/QkNb4/

Answer (score 2):

Improved Makotosan's solution further: http://jsfiddle.net/Merrinen/nZxFJ/1/

1. Uses CSS content to display hex.
2. Uses ol HTML element instead of ul.
3. Checks for start attribute in the ol element.
4. Uppercase hex values (personal preference, easy to remove).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, yet. From [this CSS-Tricks Article](http://css-tricks.com/15358-numbering-in-style/), this is what we'll be able to do in the future:

```
/*
  Examples from THE FUTURE
  No browser support at the time of this writing
*/

li::marker {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

ol {
  list-style: symbols("*" "\2020" "\2021" "\A7");
}

ul {
  list-style-type: "★";
}
```

For now, I *think* we are limited to what is available in `list-style-type`, but I could be wrong.  You can use the `:before` pseudo class, and use the `content` attribute inside there, but its not the most elegant, or easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

11 years later and CSS is now *kind of* able to handle this!

```css
@counter-style hex {
    system: alphabetic;
    symbols: '0' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'F';
    prefix: '0x';
    suffix: ' ';
}

ol {
    list-style-type: hex;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Test!</li>
    <li>Test!</li>
    <li>Test!</li>
    <li>Test!</li>
    <li>Test!</li>
</ol>
```

One Gotcha, you must know exactly how many bytes places you need to display to avoid "overflowing".
This is used in the `<ol>`->`start` attribute
For example, if you needed

- **1** Byte place  `0x0 -> 0xF`, this can be ignored as default is `1`
- **2** Byte places `0x00 -> 0xFF`, you'd add the attribute `start="17"`
- **3** Byte places `0x000 -> 0xFFF` you'd add the attribute `start="273"`

```html
<ol start="273">
    ...
</ol>
```

Full list

```
1 = 1
2 = 17
3 = 273
4 = 4369
5 = 69905
6 = 1118481
7 = 17895697
8 = 286331153
9 = 4581298449
10 = 73300775185
```

⚠️ Beyond 8, Chrome ignores the value and starts at the default `1`.

Without this the list would look something like

```
0x0    item 1
...............
0xF    item 16
0x00   item 17
...............
0xFF   item 255
0x000  item 256
```

#### You can stop reading here if you're just after the CSS, technical details following

---

The sequence follows the following `"00001 " * n`
See [OEIS A131865](https://oeis.org/A131865) for more

```ini
1 = 0001 # 1
2 = 0001 0001 # 17
3 = 0001 0001 0001 # 273
```

I made this simple function to calculate the start offset required per amount of places required

```js
const calculateStart = (n) => {
  let term = 0;
  let multiplier = 1;
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    term += multiplier;
    multiplier *= Math.pow(2, 4);
  }
  return term;
}
calculateStart(4); // 4369
```

and for completeness, you can calculate how many byte places you need by using this formula `ceil((log(N)/log(16))/2)`

```js
const calculatePlaces = (n) => Math.ceil((Math.log(n)/Math.log(16))/2);
calculateStart(16777217); // 4
```

Bringing them together

```js
calculateStart(calculatePlaces(16777217)); // 4369
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it, but i would be wary of using this on large list(s) and/or when there's a lot of different fingers in the code. its maintainable if you keep your eye on it. check it:
http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/zhuum/10/

Comment: thats how he said he wanted them smart guy. look at his example, looks exactly like mine. :)

Comment: It's not the same, the last term (10) is wrong, and getting that part right is the essence of the question.